# How to get JPA context in Springboot integration test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, cucumber

I am running a Springboot application with jpa. I am trying to set up an integration-test based on Cucumber. When in my test I try to access the repo, I get an '*org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException*' (With a message "No Session".). This only happens in my integration-test, but not in the real application. A workaround would be to put @Transactional on the method which does the call, but this does not work if I execute in new threads.

My first question would be: Why doesn't it work withouth @Transactional annotation? 
My second would be: Why doesn't it work with @Transactional annotation in new threads?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

The cucumber test:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/some-integration-test.feature")
public class IntegrationTests {}
```

The cucumber-steps:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class IntegrationSteps {

    @Autowired
    SomeRepo repo;

    @When("two updates happen at the same time")
    public void twoUpdatesHappenAtTheSameTime() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        executorService.execute(set("Thread 1"));

        executorService.execute(set("Thread 2"));

        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    public void set(String someThing) {
        Some some = repo.getOne(1234);
        repo.setSomeThing(someThing);
        repo.save(some);
    }
}
```

And the repo:

```
@Repository
public interface SomeRepo extends JpaRepository<Some, Integer> {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with `getOne()`. With `getOne()` you only get a reference to the entity. No real call to the database is executed until one tries to access the entity's fields. 
Normally these fields are loaded lazy when one uses `getOne()`, but for some reason (which is still unclear to me) this does not work in the SpringBootTest.

I've found two solutions for this issue:

1. Annotate the test with `@Transactional`. This way you will have a context to load the entity. The downside is that you still don't seem to get the most recent version of your entity. In my case I updated the entity in my code, while in test code the update was not present in the entity (even though update happened before the `getOne()` call).
2. Don't use `getOne()`, but `findById()` instead. The downside is that `findById()` is eagerly loaded, but as we only use this for our test, it will not affect the performance of our app.